# C++: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I have some code on C++.

Bird.h

```
class Bird
{
    std::string s;
    static int i;
public:
    Bird();

    ~Bird();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Bird& b);

};
```

Bird.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 
#include "Bird.h"



Bird::Bird()
{
    ++i;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<"Bird#";
    ss<<i;
    s = ss.str();
}
Bird::~Bird()
{
    i--;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Bird& b)
{
    const char* chr = (b.s).c_str();
    return os << chr << std::endl;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 
#include "Bird.h"


int Bird::i=0;

int main()
{
    Bird b();
    std::cout << b;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Bird __cdecl b(void)" (?b@@YA?AVBird@@XZ) referenced in function _main
```

But if I create `Bird b;` it's OK.
What can I do?

Comment: Show us the command you are using to compile this, probably you are not sending `Bird.cpp` to the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You meant to write `Bird b;` to create a Bird object.

`Bird b()` is a function (called `b`, taking no parameters and returning a `Bird`), which you haven't implemented.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bird b();
```

This means that `b` is a function that takes no parameters and returns a `Bird`. You then try to output the value of this function, but the function doesn't exist. Perhaps you want:

```
Bird b;
```

This says that `b` is a `Bird` that should be default constructed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of C++'s "[Most Vexing Parse.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)"

The C++ compiler thinks you're declaring a function named `b` that returns a `Bird` and then trying to print a pointer to it, as opposed to default-constructing an instance of Bird.  The linker then complains that there's no function named `b` that returns a `Bird`.  That is what this error message tries to tell you:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Bird __cdecl b(void)"
```

The Most Vexing Parse happens due to a syntactic ambiguity in the C++ language.  The ambiguity exists because the syntax for a constructor invocation looks much like the syntax for a function prototype.

The ambiguity that was resolved in a way <s>guaranteed to generate StackOverflow questions</s> that kept some tenuous backward compatibility with C, at the expense of the otherwise obvious meaning in a C++ program.

In this case, because your `Bird` is default-constructed, you can simply remove the parentheses and be done.  If you needed to call a different constructor, then the advice at the Wikipedia article linked above may help.

If you can use C++11, you can use the brace-initializer syntax to make it always unambiguous:

```
Bird b{};             // Use this if default constructed
Bird b{ ..args.. };   // Use this if you need to invoke a particular constructor
```

---

<sub>The Most Vexing Parse is a surprisingly rich topic. [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2b%2b%20most%20vexing%20parse) and read and read and read if you're truly curious.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The linker error is triggered by this

```
Bird b();
```

This is a function declaration of a function called `b`, returning a `Bird` by value. You then use the function here:

```
std::cout << b;
```

and the linker cannot find its implementation. You need

```
Bird b;   // C++03 and C++11
Bird b{}; // C++11
```

Furthermore, you should consider defining `Bird::i` in `Bird.cpp`, not `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int main()
{
    Bird b;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

the default constructor doesn't need '()'

Comment: Not only it doesn't *need* `()`, it actually doesn't *use* `()`. With `()`, it's a function, not an object.

Comment: that it！actually i misunderstand it before.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else seems to work, check if your file path does not contain special characters. This suddenly became a problem for me after adding an extra source file.